# Using Kotlin classes from jar built with kotlin-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, kotlin

I've built a Java/Kotlin hybrid lib using kotlin-maven-plugin (v 1.2.21). The lib is actually a Spring Boot app (v 1.5.9)

Now, when I declare it as a dependency in another project I face strange issues :
- My IDE (Intellij) is able to find the classes I need : auto-completion proposes me the classes, and I have no error
- But when I try to build my application, I get compilation errors, saying the packages (and therefore the class) I am trying to import don't exist.

When I expand the jar in the IDE, I can see that the classes exist in the expected package, under a BOOT-INF/classes directory.

So I am a bit confused... is there a specific config to put in kotlin-maven-plugin , so that the generated jar can be used by others ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so actually, it had nothing to do with Kotlin, but everything with Spring Boot...

Because of the change of structure in Spring Boot after 1.4.0 version as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616970/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1-4-0-jar-structure-changes), it's now required to add this config if you want to be able to import the jar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```